# How to change global navigation SP Foundation

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-foundation, master-page, navigation

I would like to ask, how I can to change default page or change global navigation in SP Foundation. I have first web collection "Home" then I have second web colletion "MY PAGE" and my second web collection "MY PAGE" is below the first web collection "HOME" in global navigation (navigate up button). I don't want that in my second web collection will see first web collection...

How I can to do it?

Thanks very much for your help!

Answer (score 1):

You would have many ways to perform changes on how global navigation behaves:

1. On Collaboration Sites (e.g. Team Site) via Site Settings -  Quick
   Launch and Top Link Bar links in the "Look and Feel" section. Go for
   manual removal of the other site collection.
2. In Publishing sites (not your case as you are using Foundation) via Site Settings  - Navigation
3. Customize the master page via SharePoint Designer 2010 (e.g. v4.master find an example pretty detailed here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh528515.aspx) - it all depends on the tools and skills you have.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I try to do it in Site settings and I manual delete Top Link Bar to my first site collection and on Top Link Bar and there is not fisrt colleton but if I clcik to "navigate button" (this is button between "Site action" and "Browse") I always see my first site collection. How I can delete or hide there my first colection? I have SP Fundation and SP designer. Thanks for your support

Comment: Q: when you say "my pages" do you actually mean My Sites and the fact that still appears on one, but not on the other, could be due to the fact that My Sites use the "Global Navigation" to show additional sites?